# Bilinear forms taking values in $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, bilinear-form

If $V$ is a finite left module over a finite ring $R$, then a bilinear form on $V$ can be taken to have values in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$?

Why is this true? Why do bilinear forms on $V$ have values in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ when $V$ is finite?

Comment: I don't understand your claim. Are you saying that all bilinear forms on finite modules over finite fields actually take values in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: No, I’m asking why can the values of the bilinear form be taken to be in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question, but if for instance $R=\mathbb{F}_4$, then the multiplication map $R\times R\to R$ is a bilinear form, which has values in $R$, and $R$ is not an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Is it a counter-example to your question ?